# esper how to use table data created by epl

Tags: esper

I'm new to esper, I want to get data stored in tbl_config. Here are some esper config file:

config.epl

```
module rms.config;

create table tbl_config(    
        id              java.math.BigDecimal    primary key,
        time            java.math.BigDecimal
);


create schema ConfigListEvent  as (
        id              java.math.BigDecimal,
        time            java.math.BigDecimal
);

@Audit
@Name("LoadConfigDataFromDBRule")
insert into ConfigListEvent
select tbl.ID as id, tbl.time as time
from ImportDataEvent,
    sql: rms ['select * from T_CONFIG'] as tbl;

@Audit
@Priority(1)
@Name("DeleteConfigDataRule")
on ConfigListEvent as evt
delete from tbl_config as tbl where evt.id = tbl.id;

@Audit
@Name("InsertConfigDataRule")
on ConfigListEvent
insert into tbl_config select *;
```

stat.epl

```
module rms.stat;
uses rms.config;

@Name("Create-PaymentContext")
create window PaymentWindow.win:time(2 hour) as PaymentRequest;


@Audit
@Name("insertPaymentRequest ")
@Priority(1)
insert into PaymentWindow select * from PaymentRequest;
```

rule.epl

```
module rms.rule;
uses rms.config;
uses rms.stat;

@Audit
@Name("xxx")
@Description("check max times per IntervalTime")
on PaymentRequest as pay
select CustomUtil.getEndTime(pay.createTime,tbl_config["time"]) as startTime from PaymentWindow as payWindow;
```

then system launch with errors:

```
com.espertech.esper.epl.expression.core.ExprValidationException: Failed to validate method-chain parameter expression 'tbl_config["time"]': Incompatible type returned by a key expression for use with table 'tbl_config', the key expression '"time"' returns 'java.lang.String' but the table expects 'java.math.BigDecimal'
```

It has confused me for a few days, Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The table has a key field "id" that is type BigDecimal. 
The expression `tbl_config["time"]` however provides the string value "time" as a key and not a BigDecimal value. Try `tbl_config[id]` assuming there is a field named 'id' in payment request that has a type BigDecimal.

The on-delete and on-insert in config.epl look a little awkward and on-merge would make this one easy to read statement.